# How to replace non-English characters with simple a-z counterparts on keyup event

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I change character input on keyup. If I enter "Ø" or other characters similar to "O", I want replace it with the character "O" automaticly. Similarly for other non-English characters.

Does somebody know, how to achieve this?

Comment: can you try to explain what are you trying to archive? you can have some sort of prematch elements and run each element entered true that and do what ever you need once there is a match, but that will actually be slow for performance

Comment: @user3580129, as the guys seemed unsure what you were asking, I edited the question a little to make it more clear. Hopefully the question is still in line with what you wanted to know. I thought it was clear enough to start with but forgive me if I misunderstood anyway. Hopefully the rephrased wording is clear and the "on hold" status is no longer needed.

Answer (score 5):

This might be starting point, based on this article on the subject http://semplicewebsites.com/removing-accents-javascript

**Highlights copied from site:**

First a map for the characters you want to replace (source from article includes an extensive mapping array)

```
var latin_map = {
    'Ø': 'O', // 'empty set' (?)
    'Á': 'A', // LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH ACUTE
    'Ă': 'A', // LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH BREVE
    ...
    'ᵥ': 'v', // LATIN SUBSCRIPT SMALL LETTER V
    'ₓ': 'x', // LATIN SUBSCRIPT SMALL LETTER X
};
```

The article then uses prototype manipulation to add `latinise` as a function on all strings

```
String.prototype.latinise = function() {
    return this.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g, function(x) { return latin_map[x] || x; })
};

// American English spelling :)
String.prototype.latinize = String.prototype.latinise;

String.prototype.isLatin = function() {
    return this == this.latinise();
};
```

Usage with protoype manipulation

```
> console.log("Mere Øl".latinise())
"Mere Ol"
```

**How to apply to your situation**:

Personally I would keep the function separate from the string prototype (but that's a personal choice).

```
latin_map = {...};
function latinize(s) {
    return s.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g, function(x) { return latin_map[x] || x;});
}
```

Then you could clean the input on keyup like so (assuming you use jQuery):

```
$('#myinput').on('keyup', function() {
   $this = $(this);
   $this.val(latinize($this.val()));
});
```

Comment: oops, had two errors in that code, now fixed. See this jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/8F6yu/)