# Google Sheets - Apps Script - Take a cell, replace some text, place it in another cell

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet of movies. They have titles. Some of the titles have weird foreign characters. I want a column for English-characters-only versions of the titles.

I found this: [How to replace non-English characters with simple a-z counterparts on keyup event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23333881/how-to-replace-non-english-characters-with-simple-a-z-counterparts-on-keyup-even)

And this: [Google script setValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32222581/google-script-setvalue)

And came up with this:

```
function StripAccents(originalTitle) {
var latin_map = {
  'Á': 'A',
  ...
  'ₓ': 'x'
}
accentedText = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(originalTitle).getValue();
return accentedText.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g, function(x) { return latin_map[x] || x;});
}
```

But it says it can't find the range. Which seems to make sense given that getRange() seems to want a number rather than a cell reference, but I don't know how else to do a cell reference and the second of those two links shows that it should work, so...help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because originalTitle has to be a string, not a range, i.e. "A1" and not A1. So, in the sheet, you have to use as following

```
=StripAccents("A1")
```

the correct code is (to be able to be used without quotes) :

```
function StripAccents(originalTitle) {
var latin_map = {
  'Á': 'A',
  'É': 'E'
}
  return originalTitle.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g, function(x) { return latin_map[x] || x;});
}
```

Comment: btw, the last line could be shorter: `return originalTitle.replace( /[^A-Za-z]/g, x => latin_map[x] || x );`